# Database Schema for storing Android Registration ID?

Tags: android, database, schema, google-cloud-messaging

What should be an effective database schema for string GCM registration ID with linkages to the user id? I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252214/how-to-store-uniquely-a-gcm-registration-id-into-mysql). It suggests:

> - For storing the registration ID itself it's better to use
>     VARBINARY(4096) column. It's more efficient than TEXT if you encode
>     the registration ID with an efficient character set (such as UTF-8).
> - For efficient search, you should still have an additional indexed
>     hash column (BINARY(32)) - we use the SHA-256 digest algorithm to get
>     the 32-bytes hash from the registration ID. The hash column doesn't
>     have to be unique. Collisions should be very rare, and even if they
>     occur, your query will give you a small number of registration IDs
>     which share the same hash, so it won't hurt performance to test in
>     your Java code which one of them (if any) actually matches the
>     registration ID you are looking for.
> - If you choose to store a unique device ID and search based on it, I
>     suggest you assign your own identifier to each device. That
>     identifier can be (for example) BIGINT (long in java). You can
>     require that the application to call your server to get a unique
>     identifier when it is first launched. You can store it on external
>     storage of the device, so that a device where the app is uninstalled 
>     and then re-installed will still have the same identifier.

But if I follow this design, if a user log out from a device and log in with there account, there is a possibility that I may not update the row with the updated user_id, as there may have a collision in the hash. But if I do not use a hash, I don't know how I can create an index on it. How should I design such a database? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In practice you can safely ignore the risk of collisions on SHA256 hashes of 4096 bytes data.

See [Is it safe to ignore the possibility of SHA collisions in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014090/is-it-safe-to-ignore-the-possibility-of-sha-collisions-in-practice) for a complete discussion about the collision risk.